# Updating bound value in object SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

Swift beginner here. I am trying to create a reusable component that simply renders either a filled or empty systemImage circle based on a value stored in state. I've put together a reproduction example below. Right now it only appears to be updating the value in state (in `formData`), but the UI doesn't seem to be updating (the circle is not filling up). I have a feeling the `Image` and `Text` components are set up to react to state changes, but I'm not sure how to fix from there. Thank you in advance!

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    @ObservedObject var formData = FormData()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Performance: \(String(formData.goals.performance))")
            Toggle(isOn: Binding(
                get: { formData.goals.performance },
                set: { formData.goals.performance = $0 }
            )) {
                Text("Performance")
            }
            ChildWrapper(isPerformanceEnabled: $formData.goals.performance)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildWrapper: View {
    @Binding var isPerformanceEnabled: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: isPerformanceEnabled ? "circle.fill" : "circle")
                .font(.system(size: 50))
                .foregroundColor(isPerformanceEnabled ? .green : .red)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isPerformanceEnabled.toggle()
                }
            Text(isPerformanceEnabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled")
        }
    }
}

struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using `@StateObject`, not `@ObservedObject`

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: It is crucial to also show how `FormData` is defined... (I tried a simple implementation and seems to be working fine)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in your model (`FormData`).

Let's examine the code:

> `@ObservedObject var formData = FormData()`

**1.** This bit is incorrect. You need `@StateObject`. Here is why:

`@ObservedObject` implies that ownership is *not* local. For example you could have an object higher up in the hierarchy or a singleton passed to this view.

The documentation states:

> Add the @ObservedObject attribute to a parameter of a SwiftUI View when the input is an ObservableObject and you want the view to update when the object’s published properties change. You typically do this to pass a StateObject into a subview.

**2.** There is no reason to pass a custom Binding to your toggle. Just pass:

`Toggle(isOn: $formData.goals.performance)`

**3.** A typical implementation of your model could look like this:

```
class FormData: ObservableObject {
    
    struct Goals {
        var performance: Bool = false
    }
    
    @Published var goals = Goals()
}
```

note here that `Goals` is a struct, which means that whenever any of its properties change, `goals` would be re-assigned and `FormData` would emit an `objectWillChange()` triggering your view to re-evaluate the `body`.

---

**Bonus Bit:**
Here is an interesting fact that *many* people get wrong...

`ChildWrapper` got a binding in order to be able to change `isPerformanceEnabled`, which is correct.
But what is exactly causing the re-evaluation?
The answer is, **not** the change to the binding, but the change to `FormData` (through the binding) that re-evaluated the parent view!
In fact, if the binding changed something that not an ancestor view would be watching, no re-evaluation would happen.

That's all. I hope that this makes sense.